# Can I fly an RNAV DP (GPS & RNAV 1 required) with no FD/AP?

Tags: faa-regulations, departure-sid, rnav, flight-director

I’m currently planning an instrument flight which includes a full stop at an airport with a RNAV (Obstacle) Departure Procedure.

The procedure plate requires RNAV 1 and GPS.

In ground school I remember learning that a FD is required when flying a RNAV 1 approach. My airplane is a Cessna 172S that has WAAS but no AP/FD.

When looking up the [FAA AC 90-100A](https://www.faa.gov/regulations_policies/advisory_circulars/index.cfm/go/document.information/documentID/73482) it talks about the FD but also mentions a “lateral deviation indicator” which would be my pink needles when loading the DP in my G1000.
The full sentences reads as follows:

> (2) Pilots must use a lateral deviation indicator (or equivalent navigation map display), flight director and/or autopilot in lateral navigation mode on RNAV 1 routes. The full-scale course deviation indicator (CDI) deflection value of ±1 NM is acceptable.

Can I now fly this RNAV DP with my WAAS C172S which is not equipped with an AP/FD or not?

It's a 2009 C172S G1000/G with PBN C2D2 but not equipped with any AP/FD. The approach plate in question is the ATASY2.ATASY Departure out of [KTDO](https://skyvector.com/airport/TDO/Ed-Carlson-Memorial-Field-South-Lewis-County-Airport).

[image: ATASY2.ATASY Departure]
Click to view

Comment: What does the AC say about FD? You wrote "it talks about the FD".

Comment: The AC only mentions the part that I quoted regarding a lateral deviation indicator, flight director and/or autopilot in lateral navigation mode.

Comment: Please let me know precisely the equipment aboard your Cessna 172 and the departure plate in question

Comment: It's a 2009 C172S G1000/G with PBN C2D2 but not equipped with any AP/FD.

The approach plate in question is the ATASY2.ATASY Departure out of KTDO.

Comment: The answer is right there in your quote from the AC. Are you having trouble parsing the “and/or”?

Comment: As @StephenS indicates, my reading would be: you can use a lateral deviation indicator (CDI), or a flight director, or an autopilot in lateral mode, or any combination.

Comment: Thank you both! That definitely answers my question.